# vuejs v-show in a custom vue component invokes TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, typeerror

I have made a following custom vue component "editable-image".

```
<template>
  <span style="position: relative; text-align: center; color: white; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" @mouseover="iconShown = true" @mouseleave="iconShown = false" @click="click">
    <img :style="`width: ${width};`" :src="imageUrl"/>
    <v-icon style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" large color="grey" v-show="iconShown">edit</v-icon>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: ['imageUrl', 'width', 'click'],
data() {
    return {
        iconShown: false
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Then, in my main component, import the above "editable-image" and let the mouse over, **TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined** occurs.

I noticed that the **v-show is the main cause of the problem**, but despite many attempts, it has not been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem is click props.

In the main component, I should have **entered the click props correctly**!